# How to add a variable to the waitnuntil method of Karate

Tags: karate, gherkin, karate-call-single

- `def title = 'some real Title'`

I want to validate (wait for) title by calling method.

- `waitUntil("document.title == '#(title)'")`

But it does not work. Any idea how I need to include title to the `wainUntil method?`.

Answer (score 1):

The `#()` placeholder system works [only for JSON](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#rules-for-embedded-expressions).

One tip: anywhere in Karate within "round brackets" you can refer to variables directly.

So try this:

```
* waitUntil("document.title == '" + title + "'")
```

Read the docs carefully also, pay attention to the part "Karate vs the Browser": https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#waituntil